# Firebase Shortening Service Vs Goog.gl

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, google-url-shortener

I was using google url shortener but had to part ways because the shortened Urls were public in the database maintained by google and can be accessed by anyone. I know Firebase is taking the place of goog.gl link shortener.

So my question today is - Is firebase links private or public? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The links generated by Firebase Dynamic Links are publicly readable. But I'm not really sure what specific operation you wonder about beyond that.

Comment: publicly readable to the whole world? even if I dont share the link with that person? Google publishes the shorturl and the mapping url which is being tapped by bots to phish.. Essentially my ask is.. I want to shorten a URL and give it explicitly to few and only those would know that there exists a shorturl

Comment: See this please  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26860/are-google-shortened-urls-goo-gl-publicized-sequential-or-secret

Comment: Within a few seconds of creating a shortened URL, Google tells me that the link has been visited by a couple of machines and browsers other than my own. This indicates that someone is crawling all of the shortened URLs, presumably via the methods described above.